# Converting multistate toggle into dropdown if available width is shrunk in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm new to flutter, I have created a multistate toggle button but I want to convert it into dropdown in case the container doesn't have enough space to show the widget.  Earlier I was using the LayoutBuilder context width but it is taking the whole width of the page not of the container containing the widget. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet what you've tried so far ,the issue you are facing and desire outcome you like to have.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right approach. LayoutBuilder would work for you, but you should factor the entire widget into its own StateLess widget and use that context to do your measurements.

LayoutBuilder provides a BoxConstraints object with minWidth, maxWidth, minHeight, maxHeight properties that you can use in your code to decide which widget to embed in the tree. The dimension of that BoxConstraints object are calculated from your Widget's immediate ancestor.

Supposed you create MyMultistateToggleBoxOrDropdownWidget() and implement its build method like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {

          // If constraints.maxWidth isn't wide enough, 
          // return a dropdown Widget,
          // otherwise return the multistate toggle box.
    }
  }
```

Now that you have a Widget that returns what you want based on width, you need to now wire it into the correct context.

What you're probably missing is that you need to wrap your custom widget inside of something that controls the screen space that you want to present your Widget inside. A SizedBox() will do for this example.

Your solution took the whole page width because that was the width of your Widget's immediate ancestor in the Widget tree.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100.0,
  height: 100.0,
  child: MyMultistateToggleBoxOrDropdownWidget()
)
```